# Сумма одинаковых чисел Java

Tags: java

Есть задача на Java (пока под консоль):
Пользователю предлагается вводить числа в диапазоне от 1 до 100 до тех пор, пока не надоест.
Когда пользователь выходит из программы, он видит на экране сумму одинаковых чисел.

Например:
1 нажато 10 раз
17 нажато 35 раз
63 нажато 12 раз
и т.д.

Как это реализовать? Как запомнить и вывести сумму?

Comment: Добавлять в Map<String, Integer>. Есть такой ключ(цифра в вашем случае) - достаем, прибавляем единицу к значению, записываем. Нет такого ключа - просто записываем в виде ключ - 1. Также посмотрите на интересные методы по работе с Map. http://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-02-14-java-8-declarative-ways-of-modifying-a-map-using-compute-merge-and-replace/

Answer (score 2):

Создайте класс обертку для HashMap  с методом add(int number)

```
public class SumMap {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(int number) {
        if (hashMap.containsKey(number)) {
            hashMap.put(number, hashMap.get(number) + 1);
        } else {
            hashMap.put(number, 1);
        }
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getMap() {
        return hashMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumMap sumMap = new SumMap();
        sumMap.add(1);
        sumMap.add(2);
        sumMap.add(1);
        sumMap.add(1);
        sumMap.add(1);
        sumMap.add(2);
        sumMap.add(2);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : sumMap.getMap().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Number=" + entry.getKey() + ", Amount=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Более элегантный add. Не такой простой на первый взгляд. Но если понять, то намного более красивый

```
public Integer add(int number) {
    return hashMap.put(number, hashMap.getOrDefault(number, 0) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
 final Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String line;
 while (!"exit".equals(line = reader.readLine())) {
        Integer count = counts.getOrDefault(line, 0);
        counts.put(line, count + 1);
 }

counts.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(String.format("%s нажато %s раз", key, value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаем `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` - ключом будет число, значением - количество его нажатий. При каждом вводе числа проверять было ли оно уже введено, если да - то берем количество вводов, если нет - то ноль. Далее вставляем в `HashMap` пару с ключом и увеличенным на 1 прежним значением.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
int num = // просим ввести число, получаем его
int val = data.containsKey(num) ? data.get(num) : 0;
data.put(num, val + 1);
```

При выходе выводим информацию:

```
for (int num : data.keySet()) {
    int val = data.get(num);
    System.out.println(num + " нажато " + val + " раз.");
}
```

Чтобы ключи выводились от меньшего числа к большему, а не вразноброс, можно использовать `TreeMap` вместо `HashMap` - он посмотрит на тип ключа - `Integer` в котором уже предусмотрен компаратор и будет сортировать пары по ключам.